# What's the short, colloquial version of "even if that were the case"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Example:

> "Do you think the neighbor killed the dog?"
>
> "I don't think so. He would have barked. **And even if that were the
>   case**, why hang him from a tree? It would've been easier to poison him or
>   stab him."

Not sure if I'm wrong but the *even if that were the case* sounds overly formal to me. However, I can't think of a colloquial version.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46632/discussion-on-question-by-alexchenco-whats-the-short-colloquial-version-of-ev).

Answer (score 2):

> **And even if that *were* the case...**

This use of *were* is the [*subjunctive mood*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood#English) as it was previously taught to students of English, and a traditionalist may insist that it is the only proper construction after *if* in *irrealis conditionals* (where *if* asks about something that might or might not take place or be true.)

However, the subjunctive is declining in use in BrE and to a lesser degree in NAmE. It's hard to say exactly why the subjunctive sounds "formal" or "stuffy" to some readers and listeners, but that is certainly the case.

Many grammar books that are held to be authoritative now present this use of the subjunctive *were* as a choice, not a prescription. For instance:

On p. 235 of "Practical English Usage", Michael Swan writes:

> We often use *were* instead of *was* after *if*. This is common in both formal and informal styles. In a formal style *were* is much more common than *was*, and many people consider it more correct, especially in American English.

Raymond Murphy, on p. 98 of "English Grammar in Use" (Cambridge) writes:

> After *if* and *wish*, you can use *were* instead of *was* .... So you can say:
>
> - *If I were you I wouldn't buy that coat.*    or   *If I was you* ...
> - *I'd go out if it weren't raining.*   or   *if it wasn't raining.*
> - *I wish it were possible.*   or   *I wish it was possible.*

The upshot for a learner of English is: you can choose to use *were* in these instances, and if you do, you will be speaking or writing correct English. If you are writing something formal such as an essay or business proposal, it might be a wiser choice to use the subjunctive, but even then *was* is perfectly acceptable.

In everyday speech and writing, you will encounter *both* verb forms, and you may even occasionally be "corrected" for using *was* instead of *were;* but any language is used and created by its speakers, not by grammarians, and today either *was* or *were* is considered "correct", and the usage of *were* is declining.

In the case of the phrase you ask about, it could be written colloquially as:

> **And even if that *was* the case...**

...or you might want to dispense entirely with *were* and *was* and write:

> **And even *in that* case...**

...or dispense with the clause altogether:

> **And why would you hang him from a tree anyway?**

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten it to *even then*:

> "Do you think the neighbor killed the dog?"
>
> "I don't think so. He would have barked.  Even then why hang him on a tree?